# Wrap every anchor with <code> tag

Tags: html, css

How do I make so that every link is wrapped around the `<code>` tag?

`attribute:code` doesn't work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>a{attribute:code}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of doing `<code><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></code>`

Comment: This isn't even a valid CSS.

Comment: You will need to use jQuery or Javascript for this.

Comment: Really? I can do for example: <style>a{color:red}</style> but I can't do all text with the link tag also has the code tag...

Answer (score 2):

CSS (*Cascading **Style** Sheet*) is used only to make things look prettier, and position them.

If you want to make changes to your DOM (Current html body), you will need Javascript.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has a function called [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), that wraps the desired tags within another one, like this:

```js
$('a').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<code></code>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a><br>
<a href="www.twitter.com">Twitter</a><br>
<a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a><br>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a><br>
```

This will wrap every anchor tag with the `<code>` tag.

If you're not a fan of jQuery, which is strange since it is awesome, there is a pure Javascript solution:

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
   var org_html = anchors[i].innerHTML;
   new_html = "<code>" + org_html + "</code>";
   anchors[i].innerHTML = new_html;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a><br>
<a href="www.twitter.com">Twitter</a><br>
<a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a><br>
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would simply like to style the appearance of your `<a>` tags to be the same as a `<code>` tag, then consider applying the default `<code>` styles to your `<a>` tags.

Most browsers will apply this style to `<code>` tags by default:

```
font-family: monospace;
```

So you could apply the same to your `<a>` tags, like this:

```
a {
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: That's another amazing solution :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use to add any content before and after using before and after psude elements

```css
a::before { content: "<code>"; }

a::after{ content: "</code>"; }
```

```html
<a href="www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a><br>
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a><br>
```

Comment: @PhiterFernandes is correct, `content` does not support HTML.